# Проверка правильности заполнения формы в Java EE

Tags: java, jsp, java-ee

Всем привет. Делаю регистрацию с помощью сервлета, всё работает. Остается только вопрос: в каком месте делать проверку правильности заполнения формы. К примеру, заново отправлять пользователя на .jsp, если такой юзернейм уже зарегестрирован?

Answer (score 1):

Ну так Вы посмотрите, как делают остальные :).

Базовый вариант: после отправки формы Вы её на сервере проверяете и, если [например] имя занято, отправляете человека обратно на ту же форму. Важно при этом вывести **внятное сообщение об ошибке** и **заполнить поля** введёнными значениями, чтоб человеку заново не пришлось всю форму заполнять.

Расширенный вариант для удобства пользователей: проверка в момент заполнения (или при нажатии кнопки `submit`) с помощью JS (т.е. AJAX). Но она, естественно, ни в коем случае **не заменяет проверку на сервере**.

Answer (score 0):

Если связанно с базой данных то проверку надо делать в той части которая имеет к ней доступ. В данном случае я думаю это (сервлет) а может JSP. Зависит от того где у Вас доступ к базе.
Остальную проверку лучше конечно делать на клиенте. Но опять таки связанно с тем какую технологию используете (JSF, Struts и т.п.). Некоторые технологии позволяют делать проверку только на сервере. Но в данном случае я понимаю, что это JSP так, что на клиенте.